# Math.random() outcome seems flipped

Tags: javascript, symbols

I'm currently playing with a true or false script on the outcome from Math.Random()

code is as following

```
var win = Math.random() >= (percent / 100);
        
        if (win === true) {
           console.log("true")
        } else {
            console.log("false")
        }
```

- In this case `percent` is 50 by default. If i put the percent to 90% it keeps returing false more or less all the time `Math.random() >= (90 / 100);` .. But since you only have 10% to return false, thats strange
- If i set the percent to 1% it keeps returning true (but i suppose it almost always should return false, since you technically only have 1% chance to return true).

Is the >= (Greater than or equal too) flipped the wrong side around - it does feel like you get less chance of win = true, even if you put in 90(percent) / 100

Hope someone can clarify if my symbols are wrongly placed

Comment: You just have the logic backwards. Math.random() gives you a number between 0 and 1. The probability that it's larger than 0.9 is 0.1.

Comment: So technically, swapping the swap the >= / <= would solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If percentage = 90, this means that `Math.random` has to be 0.9 or greater, which return true in 10% of the cases.

So reverse the comparator:

```
var win = Math.random() < (percent / 100);
```

Comment: I really had the thought that it might be the >= / <= that was wrong.. But i wasn't too sure regarding it. (edit < )

Thank you alot for confirming it!

Comment: The real opposite operator of `>=` is `<`,  not `<=`. Edited...